# How to save and reset form input after wrong captcha?

Tags: forms, cookies, input, session-cookies, save

I have a form in which people have to fill in a couple of input fields. The problem is: if someone puts in a wrong captcha-code or any other inputfield goes wrong, than they have to start over, filling the form once again. I know that it's possible to use cookies to save the input and reset it back, but I can't find any code for this problem? I have 7 input fields and 2 select fields....

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax for this, there are numerous code online for this.

Use Jquery.

Comment: Can you give me an example or a demo with code or something? Because I know I have to use them, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

See any of these links helps you

http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin
http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/qaptcha/
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/22/21-free-captcha-sources/